# Regex to match all except data-value attribute from string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am looking for a regex to skip `data-value="4"` attribute from string for example I have a string i.e

```
Hello this is string <sfpart contenteditable="false" data-value="4">&rlm;</sfpart> and the 4 number in string
```

Now in the above string I want to replace `4` with lets say `<span class="yellow">4</span>` but not `4` inside the `data-value="4"`

I can grab `4` and replace it with the `<span class="yellow">4</span>` by doing below code

```
const reg = new RegExp('('4')', 'gi');
const str = str.replaceAll(reg, '<span class="yellow">$1</span>');
```

But the issue is above regex picking `4` inside `data-value` attribe and replacing it with the html span tags i.e `data-value="<span class="yellow">4</span>`" so I want skip that part.

Any genuis to help?

Comment: What is `<sfpart>`?

Comment: @Andy this is the HTML tag coming from DB anything inside data-attribute of those tags needs to be skipped so that it would not replace i.e `data-value="<span class="yellow">4</span>"`

Answer (score 1):

Use [assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In this case a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!data-value=")\d+
```

This will ensure you match only the character 4 that is not immediately preceded by the `data-value` attribute name (as well as the `="` that prefixes the attribute value).

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/SzPUOx/1

Comment: This is close enough but it has one issue now lets say if `data-value="14"` in this case it will fail I need anything inside `data-value="xxx"` to be skipped

Comment: Remember `4` would be dynamic it could be anything i.e `4`,`42454`,`test` an open text field, any part of the entered input matches with `data-value="xxx"` it should skip it i.e input is `569` and `data-valu="15695"` it should skip either.

Comment: Simply replace 4 with what you are looking to match. I cannot meaningfully modify my answer unless you give me the exact string you are hoping to match. Otherwise, to match literally anything, simply replace 4 with `.*`, but I suspect this is not the desired behavior.

Comment: What I am looking for is any input number contains inside `data-value="xx"` attribute it should skip entire data-value attribute for example `data-value="12456"` and the input number entered is `4` we can see `4` is exist in `data-value="12345"`  hence it should skip data-value.

Comment: Your regex `((?<!data-value=")4)` is working fine if data-value attribute start from first matching digit for example if `data-value="4123"` it skips (notice `4` is at the beginning) but if `data-value="1234"` or `data-value="142"` (`4` in middle or at last) it doest not skip.

Comment: You cannot tell regex to skip or ignore certain parts of the string, you can only tell it to match certain characters while asserting (with a lookaround) that it is not relatively positioned to some other characters. Since you mentioned you want to match numbers, I will assume that this means that you want the string to replace to be digits, and if the value of the `data-value` attr happens to also be digits then you do not want to match that. In that case, see the edit to my answer where I replace the simple 4 with any number of digits.

Comment: Your previous answer was fine as it will not have digit always actually there is a search field when user input anything (digit, string..) we are highlighting the input data from that visible paragraph which works fine. However in that paragraph there could be HTML tags and the issue is from those tags search also get the data and highlight by adding HTML hence HTML tags withing lets say data-value attribute not showing properly. Hence I want to not pick the data-value part any single character matches inside data-value it should not include data-value attribute

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using regex to match HTML tags and attributes. Use DOMParser to parse your string instead, and then iterate through all the `nodeChildren` and perform the replacement in text nodes (which will have a `nodeType` of `3`):

```js
const string = 'Hello this is string <sfpart contenteditable="false" data-value="4">&rlm;</sfpart> and the 4 number in string';

const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsedNode = parser.parseFromString(string, "text/html").body;

for (let i = 0; i < parsedNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
  const node = parsedNode.childNodes[i];
  if (node.nodeType === 3) {
    const replacementNode = document.createElement('span');
    replacementNode.innerHTML = node.textContent.replaceAll(/(\d+?)/gi, '<span class="yellow">$1</span>');
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(replacementNode, node);
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}

console.log(`Input:\n${string}`);
console.log(`Output:\n${parsedNode.innerHTML}`);
document.querySelector('#input').innerHTML = string;
document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = parsedNode.innerHTML;
```

```css
#input,
#output {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
}

span.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<strong>Input:</strong>
<div id="input"></div>

<strong>Output:</strong>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Terry, however I do not want to skip HTML tags all I need to only replace digit inside string with `<span class="yellow">4</span>` so end result would be something like this `Hello this is string <sfpart contenteditable="false" data-value="4">&rlm;</sfpart> and the <span class="yellow">4</span> number in string`

Comment: @MichaelFine How's the code "skipping HTML tags"? It skips parsing attributes inside the tag itself, which you said you didn't want. You want to replace the digits in text nodes, which the code does.

Comment: Terry check zr0gravity7 answer above it does the trick but needs a minor tweak currently its failing if value is `14` instead of just `4` checkout his example demo link

Comment: @MichaelFine Yes but that answer can only handle a single attribute. If you have any arbitrary `data-` attribute, like `data-foo="4"` then it will fail again, since you need to create a lookbehind for every imaginable data attribute.

Comment: the attribute will always be `data-value="xxx"` this is for sure

Comment: My answer should be used with caution, I would opt for a more scalable and generalized solution like the one proposed by @Terry if you intend to do this operation (sifting through attributes of DOM elements) in numerous places or for various attributes. Using RegEx to parse HTML or other source code is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Terry your answer not covering other cases for example if the input is `4` it will add `span` tags to highlight other than inside HTML tags but if the input is `14` it will skip all `4` in the sting plus I need to add span in any input which is inside any other HTML tags i.e `<div>4</div>` should also be replaced with `<div><span class="yellow">4</span></div>` in your solution it wont. the only place I need to skip is inside `data-value="xx"` attribute other than that it should add span tags and highlight.

Comment: The reason of ignoring `data-value="xxx"` is bcz when it append span tags inside data-value attribute the HTML does not parse browser never recognize and it shows a weird output on browser if you have any solution for that feel free to share.

Comment: @Terry your answer is close enough if you could only fine tune it a bit so that it not skip all HTML tags but only the data-value attribute if it exist rest it add span for the input like its doing if even it exist inside div, p or any other HTML tag.